# Object Error in JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Am doing an AJAX call on click of a button in a jsp. but if i open the page and leave it idle for 5minutes and i try to click the button Object : object error is coming. but i click on the button 2nd time the ajax call works fine. it happens only if the page is idle for more than 5 minutes. any idea what i need to do to solve this? below is my ajax function. Thanks in advance

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            cache : false,
            url : "checkActualDataExist.htm?id=" + Math.random() + "&month="
                    + month + "&year=" + year + "&location=" + location,
            success : function(response) {

                if (response != "") {
                    if (confirm(response)) {
                        $("#uploadForm").submit();
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#uploadForm").submit();
                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Give exact error details.

Comment: after 5 min of page being idle i get an alert saying Object : object. and i click once again it works fine.

Comment: your javascript looks fine, since you didn't provide the exact return error i could only assume that it's related to server side, seems like the server (jsp) responds differently depending on request timing. one suggestion is to check you're session timeout config on server side (maybe session is being expired very fast)

Comment: if the session time out happens then after the error i should not be able to continue further rt? i click 2nd time it works fine.

Comment: Try changing your alert(e) to console.log(e), and check the console for the exact error. That should help you find them problem more easily.

Comment: check the status code and error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a network error. Check whether there are any server timeouts. If the session is closed then this error will occur.

Comment: Yes. There was a session timeout happening in the server. Now thats fixed. Thanks.